# Редактирование торрент-файла через C#

Tags: c#, парсер

Как можно с помощью C# отредактировать содержимое торрент-файла? А именно интересует поле "описание". Нашел только библиотеку для чтения содержимого, но не изменения.

Comment: ну я  не знаю. сходу гуглится https://torrentlibrary.codeplex.com/ где написано "reading, modification, and writing. "

Comment: Вы можете привести пример работы с этой библиотекой? А в частности редактирование поля "Описание"? Потому что из вкладки с документацией там ничего про редактирование дельного нет, только про чтение.

Comment: не могу. я не разбирал торрент файлы. я всего лишь не согласился с тем, что ничего не находится для редактирования. не согласен и "дельного ничего нет"..исходя из вкладки "дока" файл разбирается в некий словарь с элементами и списками (по факту DOM), который можно менять и сохранять. Пример чтения и сохранения там есть, создание элементов тоже, а замену имеющихся скорее всего подскажет IDE по именам методов..